# Does freeradius support redis cluster and if yes in which release

Tags: freeradius

While searching I found that the latest version of freeradius which is 3.2.X doesn't support using redis cluster. but in the github repository I found that they support it in [the redis rlm configuration file](https://github.com/FreeRADIUS/freeradius-server/blob/master/raddb/mods-available/redis) but I do not where do I found it or if this version is stable or not.

I am expecting to make a configuration for the accounting requests to use redis cluster as a back-end database. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redis clusters are only supported in the unreleased development version (that will become v4). It's not supported in any released stable version.

It's possible to use a Redis proxy that supports clusters in between FreeRADIUS and Redis to work around it if needed.

Comment: Thank you very much I am so thankful. I tried to compile the unreleased version but it still have some issues. do you recommand any proxy that supports redis cluster. that would really help me.